# Compute Engine Autoscaler : choice of the machine to terminate

Tags: scalability, google-compute-engine

The [Autoscale (Beta) documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/#handling_instance_terminations) states :

> *[The Autoscaler]* randomly selects the virtual machines to terminate.

This is a problem because a machine may be running a long process, and get abruptly terminated... even if other machines are idle! Do you know a workaround to prevent tasks from being aborted ?

It would make sense IMO to use a heuristic to determine the machine to be terminated, based on CPU or other metrics. The [shutdown script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/shutdownscript) can be used to perform some cleanup actions and [gives a 90s relief](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances#delete_timeout), but doesn't solve the abortion problem.

My use case is :

- Process user-submitted tasks in Google Compute Engine.
- Let the Autoscaler create new instances when CPU utilization increases.
- Let the Autoscaler terminate instances when CPU utilization decreases.

Tasks may run for a while (up to 15mn).

Answer (score 1):

You are the correct. The Auto-Scaler does terminate instances randomly. From my understanding, the Google Auto-Scaler team is aware of the customer demand on this and are working to get this feature implemented.

Comment: Thanks Vaqar. If you have some forum links discussing this, I'd be glad to read them.